# Как избавиться от ошибок "open_basedir restriction in effect" в WordPress? Вирус или нет?

Tags: php, wordpress, centos, vps, vesta

У меня VPS с несколькими сайтами на WordPress.
Недавно на всех сайтах стали появляться вот такие ошибки в огромных количествах:

```
[Thu Mar 23 15:06:02.400144 2023] [php7:warn] [pid 594] [client 114.119.143.251:43476] PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/htdrscol.txt) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/mysite.ru/public_html:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/mysite.ru/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(489) : runtime-created function on line 1

[Thu Mar 23 15:06:02.400280 2023] [php7:warn] [pid 594] [client 114.119.143.251:43476] PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/smmpgafx.txt) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/mysite.ru/public_html:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/mysite.ru/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(495) : runtime-created function on line 1
```

Я отключил в конфигурации PHP вывод ошибок и сайты стали работать как ни в чем не бывало. НО ошибки стали переполнять логи — за день набивается по несколько гигабайт и место на сервере заканчивается.

Недавно на одном из сайтов было обнаружено вредоносное ПО (фишинг). Возможно появление ошибок как-то связано с этим фактом.

Я не понимаю что это за файлы со странными адресами вида /tmp/smmpgars.txt
Меня смущает что они из папки /tmp/ и что у них разрешение .txt. Wordpress не должен запускать текстовые файлы из /tmp/ (или я чего-то не знаю).

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться. Вирус это или нет? Если вирус, то как его найти?
Если не вирус, то как избавиться от ошибок?

ПС: Сервер CentOS, стоит Vesta. Кстати, недавно её обновляли, может с этим как-то связано.

Comment: Или вирь или "нормальная" работа какого-то плагина/кода.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/open_basedir-restriction-in-effect-26/#post-12273510

Comment: Вообще-то, в /tmp никто писать не должен. Так что, скорее всего, вирус. Поставьте Wordfence и просканируйте.

Comment: @KAGGDesign ну как это не должен? Любая загрузка вначале делается в tmp_dir, а потому переносится куда надо. Другой вопрос почему там что-то остаётся, а не удаляется. (с таким поведением я как-то сталкивался на виндовых недосерверах. Уже не помню причин.)